# Google Map Number Markers

Tags: google-maps

I have to show numerous (approx 500) numerical markers on a map, I generated 300 using

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/

However it only goes up to 300 - how do others show large number of numerical markers on a map?

Comment: Not sure if this fits into your application requirements, but with that many markers you may also want to look into Clusters...http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the Google Charts API, with pins:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html#pins

Or bubbles:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html#bubbles

Here is a bubble that shows 500:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|500|C6EF8C|000000

Comment: The google charts infographics api has been deprecated, so if you're planning to use this in the long run, best to find another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do it:

1. Generate the other images your self
2. Generate the images dynamically
3. Use a custom overlay instead of a marker and display HTML